# add value from data grid view to database using parameters c#

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server-2008, datagridview, parameters

i want to update and add the values of column in data grid view with  columns in the database where itemname = column 1 using  parameters and i got this code

```
 using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection("Data Source=(local);Initial Catalog=inventory;Integrated Security=True"))
        {

            connection.Open();
            using (SqlTransaction transaction = connection.BeginTransaction())
            using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("UPDATE product SET quantity = quantity + @quantity where itemname = @itemname", connection, transaction))
            {
                SqlParameter pQuantity = command.Parameters.Add("@quantity", SqlDbType.Int );
                SqlParameter pItemName = command.Parameters.Add("@itemname", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50);

                for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.Rows.Count; i++)
                {
                    pQuantity.Value = Convert.ToInt32(dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[5].Value);
                    pItemName.Value = dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value ?? DBNull.Value;
                    command.ExecuteNonQuery();
                }
                command.ExecuteNonQuery();
                transaction.Commit();

            }
        }
```

and when i press the button nothing happen

Comment: need more information..like database getting updated?

Comment: add a breakpoint at update query and check the values being posted and let me know

Comment: how i can show you or tell you what i never use breakpoint :)

Comment: dont worry ll guide you..vs version ?

Comment: First check your button is fired or not....

Comment: 2012 ultimate ty for your help

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/xyqzUcp.png